# Mensagem retornando nome usuário da Session usando str_replace

Tags: php

Preciso de uma ajuda para colocar o nome do usuário no topo da página. No php eu consegui fazer, (se der um echo "$nomeUsuario" ele funciona) mas perde toda formatação, então preciso que seja feito um replace no html. Vejam

```
if (Session::getValue('logado')):

            switch (Session::getValue('departamento')) {
                case '1':

                    $menu = 'menu/admin.html';

                    $nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];

                    $string = 'Olá ' . $nomeusuario . ' seja bem vindo!';

                    $nova = str_replace('#TMSG#', $nomeusuario, $string);

                    var_dump($nova);
```

Comment: Parece não ter sentido algum. Afinal, o quê pretende substituir? Como está atualmente e como quer que fique com a substituição?

Comment: Não está substituindo nada com nada e há varaiveis sem ser utilizadas.

Answer (score 1):

Então eu sei que você quer em `str_replace`, mas é possivel fazer pelo `echo`:

você deve ir na parte desejada do site e usar:

```
<?php 
  echo "$nomeusuario seja bem vindo(a)!";
?>
```

> Ta mas vai ficar sem formatação

Simples use CSS:
**EXEMPLO:**
*HTML:*

```
<div id="saudacao">
<?php 
  echo "$nomeusuario seja bem vindo(a)!";
?>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#saudacao {
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Para colocar um tamanho coloque dentro de um um `<h>`

Como falei no começo, sei que não foi assim que você pediu mas foi assim que eu sempre usei. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Problema é que tentei fazer assim, mas não funcionou. Veja como fiz:
<?php 
  echo "$nomeusuario seja bem vindo(a)!";
?>
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

Não sei é por causa de estar usando o site em MVC.

Comment: Acho que é pq vc tem que declarar a variável `$nomeusuario` antes, tenta assim: `<div id="saudacao">
<?php $nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome'];
  echo "$nomeusuario seja bem vindo(a)!";
?>
</div>`

Comment: Também não funcionou. Nem assim: $nomeusuario = $_SESSION['nome']; print $nomeusuario;

Comment: @Eduehi como o Gustavox falou, consertesa o problema vem pois a variavel não esta declarada para o PhP então é como ela não existice.

Comment: Não funciona, não sei o porque. Já tentei fazer assim. Mas acho que o unico jeito vai ser com replace mesmo.

Comment: @Eduehi vish aqui nunca deu problema, isso é estranho. Mas com o replace deve funcionar, mas n uso ele a muito tempo então tenho que dar uma pesquisada